Importing isolines/contours in R terra package
I am attempting to import isolines/elevation contours into r using the terra package in R but I can't get it to import the elevation, just the lines.
> sjre_bath = vect(sj_bath)
Warning message:
[vect] Z coordinates ignored 

I import using the vect function, but it ignores the z coordinates. I'm hoping I'm just using the wrong function or need to specify what the z coordinates mean somewhere?
sjre_bath
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : lines 
 dimensions  : 2986, 9  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 690934.6, 691637.1, 4598198, 4599186  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 source      : StJoe.shp
 coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N (EPSG:32616) 
 names       :  FID_     Entity         Layer Color   Linetype Elevation LineWt RefName Elev_m
 type        : <int>      <chr>         <chr> <int>      <chr>     <num>  <int>   <chr>  <num>
 values      :     0 LWPolyline C-TOPO-MAJR-N    14 Continuous       810     25      NA  246.9
                   0 LWPolyline C-TOPO-MAJR-N    14 Continuous       810     25      NA  246.9
                   0 LWPolyline C-TOPO-MAJR-N    14 Continuous       815     25      NA  248.4

This is what the file I'm loading in looks like. The elevation seems to still be there, but just not used?
> contour(sjre_bath)
Error in contour.default(sjre_bath) : no proper 'z' matrix specified

If I try to make a contour plot it says that the z matrix is not specified (because it ignored it) so I think the package has the function, and I'm just missing something simple.

Pointing, if possible, to data source will help.

I'm not sure I quite understand the the problem here -- contour() is a SpatRaster method to plot contour lines, but you have a vector (of contour lines?), StJoe.shp, imported as SpatVector. Do you want to plot those shapes? Or what does "importing" mean in this context, what are your next planned steps?

It's not public data, so I'm not sure how I could share it. But my end goal is to either make this into a raster instead, or at the bare minimum be able to read the elevation.
When I plot it, I get the lines, I just don't get the elevation of them.

From the data seem the Elevation is there, you can plot it with terra::plot() function or add them over already plotted raster with terra::lines() function. terra::contour() which you tried creates isolines/contours from raster.
